# Registration and tracking member's information

Tags: java, android, registration, tracking

I've added Google and Facebook login. What is the best way to get details from those who don't use Google or Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need a server.

Develop the API for registration and login (maybe you want to use [oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/)), then in your Android APP build the forms that gather the informations and pass them to your server APIs.

There are a lot of tutorial around the web. Stack Overflow is not the right place for tutorials. Try to do it and when you are stucked from a specific problem, you could ask here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) database to register users and save their information.
also you can use [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017) or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) to save info.